# DocuSign Error Using AchorString With Tiff Files (C# SDK)

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign C# SDK to send documents. I am using the AnchorString feature to help DocuSign determine where the signature and date should go on the document. This works fine for PDF files, but I get the below error when using Tiff files (LZW and CCITT4 formats). Is there a more preferred method to anchor the signature to the document? I can't seem to find much online regarding this error.

**The following error occurs when I call *CreateEnvelop* using the AnchorStrings feature (code included below):**

*Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
 "errorCode": "ANCHOR_TAB_STRING_NOT_FOUND",
 "message": "The specified Anchor Tab string was not found in the document. Anchor Tab String \"Signature:\" not found.Anchor Tab String \"Signed:\" not found."
}*

**Code:**

```
  Signer signer = new Signer();

  DateSigned dateSigned = new DateSigned() { AnchorString = "Signed:", Name = "Signed:", AnchorXOffset = "35" };

  signer.Tabs.DateSignedTabs.Add(dateSigned);      
  signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();    
  SignHere signHere = new SignHere() { AnchorString = "Signature:", Name = "Signature:", AnchorXOffset = "65" };
  signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);
```

**Update:**

The *ANCHOR_TAG_PROCESSING_FAILURE* error that I was getting was because I didn't have the *FileExtension* property set to TIFF. I updated the above error to what I receive with that property set.

*Note: I do not receive that error message when I create the envelope without the anchor string.*

Cross posted: https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W00006JzLHgSAN/error-using-achorstring-with-tiff-files-c-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Anchor string positioning won't work when the source document uses an image format such as tiff, jpg, png, gif, etc. You'll need to use exact positioning.

### Details

The anchor string system works by looking for the literal characters of the anchor string. In your case, "Signed:" So those characters need to be in the pdf document. (DocuSign converts all incoming document formats to PDF.)

In the case of original docs that use image formats such as tiff, the original document does not include the characters "Sign:" (or any other characters). Instead, image formats contain an image of the words in the document.

Since the document is an image, the words can't be located. You'll need to use absolute positioning for your tags. (Or switch to a different source doc format such as .docx, .html, .pdf, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Larry. I wasn't sure how that would work with an image. I assumed that they used some type of image recognition for images, since TIFF is in DocuSign's supported formats. My documents are dynamic, so the Y coordinates will always be different. Looks like I might have to calculate it.

Comment: Another option, depending on your business case, is to add a "signature page" which will follow the tiff document(s). The signer will just see a flow of pages. Since you're creating the signature page, you can use html or pdf source and anchor text positioning will work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your document can't get processed, it is not about way you use anchor, it is document not valid

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sol. Please see my recent edit.